# strange behaviour when performing where inside a wherehas

Tags: php, laravel

I'm experiencing some weird behaviour when performing a where clause inside a whereHas function. If run the following:

The uuid param is: '96914c50-0c36-11e8-8819-e174932b5901';

```
...    
$this->builder->whereHas('document.group', function ($q) use ($uuid) {
           return $q->where('uuid', $uuid);
        });
...
```

The resulting query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE exists (SELECT * FROM `documents` WHERE `comments`.`document_id` = `documents`.`id` and `uuid` = '1')
```

Notice the uuid gets parsed to a 1.
To be clear, when i var_dump the $uuid inside my whereHas, i am still receiving the right value.

So i went on and try the following:

```
...
    $group = DocumentGroup::where('uuid', $uuid)->value('id');

            $this->builder->whereHas('document', function ($q) use ($group) {
                $q->whereHas('group', function ($q) use ($group) {
                    return $q->where('uuid', $group);
                });
            });
...
```

Inside my second whereHas, the value of $group is 2755, which is the correct id.

But the resulting sqls are:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `document_groups` WHERE `uuid` = '96914c50-0c36-11e8-8819-e174932b5901' LIMIT 1

SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE exists (SELECT * FROM `documents` WHERE `comments`.`document_id` = `documents`.`id` and exists (SELECT * FROM `document_groups` WHERE `documents`.`group_id` = `document_groups`.`id` and `uuid` = '1'))
```

Again, the id gets parsed to a 1. Does anyone have a reason why this is happening?

UPDATE:

After some more testing, the result is even weirder.

The following code:

```
...
$this->builder->whereHas('document', function ($q) use ($uuid) {
            $q->whereHas('group', function ($q) use ($uuid) {
                $q->where('title', '=', "ole");
            });
        });
...
```

provides the following sql:

```
SELECT count(*) as aggregate FROM `comments` WHERE exists (SELECT * FROM `documents` WHERE `comments`.`document_id` = `documents`.`id` and exists (SELECT * FROM `document_groups` WHERE `documents`.`group_id` = `document_groups`.`id` and `title` = '1'))
```

UPDATE2:

I 'fixed' it by using whereRaw instead of where:

```
$this->builder->whereHas('document', function ($q) use ($uuid) {
            $q->whereHas('group', function ($q) use ($uuid) {
                return $q->whereRaw('uuid = "' . $uuid . '"');
            });
        });

SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE exists (SELECT * FROM `documents` WHERE `comments`.`document_id` = `documents`.`id` and exists (SELECT * FROM `document_groups` WHERE `documents`.`group_id` = `document_groups`.`id` and uuid = "96914c50-0c36-11e8-8819-e174932b5901"))
```

Comment: it doesn't make any sense why it is behaving like this. What is your laravel version? 1. could please check $group data type? Confirm is it string. 2. Could you also please try with $q->where('uuid', '=', $group);

Comment: Laravel version is 5.5. the datatype is of uuid is "CHAR", i also tried the alternate where version you provided, but the result stays the same

Comment: It sounds like you have the uuid column as primary key, but still using the default model setting of `$incrementing = true`. Try setting it to false.

Comment: Setting incrementing to false gives the same result. But to be clear. The uuid is not my primary key. I still have a normal id. The uuid is just used as a reference when searching items.